# How to find the shift number from a word and it's ciphered version in python?

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

So I'm currently stuck on this part of the challenge: If the command is *decode*, then the program should prompt for a string to decode and a plain-text word that appears in the text (decoded string). The output should be the rotation needed to decode the string and the decoded string (text).

1. If the program receives one word that belongs in the decoded string, then the program searches for a rotation that finds that word in the decoded string. That is the proper rotation. Finding that rotation is the goal of the program.
2. If no rotation is found, then the program should indicate this fact.

```
#User Greeting
greeting = print("Hello! Welcome to the Caesar Cipher!")

#List Command Options
prompt1 = input("Select a commend: \n'e' to encode,\n'd' to decode, or\n'q' to quit\n")
while prompt1 not in ["e", "d", "q"]:
    print("Invalid choice")
    prompt1 = input("Select a commend: \n'e' to encode,\n'd' to decode, or\n'q' to quit\n")

#Encode Option
if prompt1 == "e":
  prompt2 = input("Please enter a lowercase word string to encode: ")
  c = 0
  for c in prompt2:
    if not c.isalpha():
      print("Letters only please!")
      prompt2 = input("Please enter a lowercase word string to encode: ")
    elif c.isupper():
      print("No uppercase please!")
      prompt2 = input("Please enter a lowercase word string to encode: ")
  prompt3 = int(input("Please enter a rotation number between 1-25: "))
  if prompt3 not in range(1,25):
    print("Out of range")
    prompt3 = input("Please enter a rotation number between 1-25: ")
  output = ""
  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  for c in prompt2:
    if c in alphabet:
      output += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c)+prompt3)%(len(alphabet))]
  print("Your cipher is: " + output)

#Decode Option
if prompt1 == "d":
  prompt4 = input("Please enter a lowercase word string to decode: ")
  c = 0
  for c in prompt4:
    if not c.isalpha():
      print("Letters only please!")
      prompt4 = input("Please enter a lowercase word string to decode: ")
    elif c.isupper():
      print("No uppercase please!")
      prompt4 = input("Please enter a lowercase word string to decode: ")
  prompt5 = input("Please enter a lowercase word in the decoded string: ")
  for c in prompt5:
    if not c.isalpha():
      print("Letters only please!")
      prompt5 = input("Please enter a lowercase word in the decoded string: ")
    elif c.isupper():
        print("No uppercase please!")
        prompt5 = input("Please enter a lowercase word in the decoded string: ")
  numberoutput = ""
  list(prompt4)

  print("Your rotation number is: " + numberoutput)

#Quit Option
if prompt1 == "q":
  print("Goodbye! Come back soon!")
```

Comment: this looks like a programming assignment. Could you please explain what is not working with your program?

Comment: I am not sure how find the rotation number. I would assume I'd use a loop where the index of the ciphered word is equaled to the index of the first word, but what I'm struggling with is how to do that correctly. I've tried:

prompt4 = "dbu"

prompt5 = "cat" (so a shift of one)

numberoutput = ""

c = 0

list(prompt4)

list(prompt5)

while c in prompt4 != c in prompt 5:

  c = c +1

now I'm not sure how to get the number.